# Unable to connect to MySQL Server with both the MySQL Command Line Client and mysql connector for python

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I recently setup MySQL Server on my computer. But the command line client asks for the password and simply closes without showing anything.
The mysql connector for python can't connect to it either.

```py
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(username='username',passwd='password')
```

Just gives

```
InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)
```

I saw somewhere that setting the host to localhost might help.

```py
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(username='username',passwd='password',host='localhost')
```

But even then:

```
InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)
```

The target machine actively refused it?

This already happened once and I reconfigured MySQL Server from the MySQL Community Installer which temporarily got it to work on both the command line client and with the python connector. Is there any way to permanently fix this?

Here are the versions of software I'm using:

- MySQL Server 8.0.21
- MySQL Server Installer 1.34.4.0
- Python 3.8.2
- JupyterLab 2.1.2

EDIT: Should've mentioned I'm running Windows 10.

Comment: if you're using *nix try this command. `sudo systemctl status mysql.service`. and see it's active or not.

Comment: it seems to me the MySQL server isn't running yet! you need to start it!

Comment: `sudo netstat -a | grep mysql`, if you don't see MySQL daemon then you need to start it `systemctl start mysql`

Comment: @Code Thanks but I'm running Windows. Do you happen to know the equivalent commands? I think MySQL Installer is supposed to do the starting.

Comment: In windows you want to go to 'services' and look for  MySQL80. See if its running and if not just double click it and start it on. Check that 'Start type' is on 'Automatic'

Comment: You may want to use MySQL Workbench, It may help you to begin with the  Database

Comment: @Erick Going to services and starting MySQL80 worked. I've set the start type to automatic too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @Erick, I got MySQL working for me. So MySQL is usually installed as a service on windows and is set to manually start every session. This was why reconfiguring worked but only that once. What you need to do is [go to services](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/ways-access-services-windows),   and look for MySQL80. If it isn't already running (which was what happened to me), double-click it to start, and set 'Start type' to automatic so that the MySQL Server starts automatically during system start-up. For me, doing this made both the client and python able to connect to the server :).

Comment: Maybe you want to vote me up and place the issue as solved

Comment: @Erick I'm sorry I don't have enough reputation yet to vote you up visibly.

Answer (score 1):

#replace username as user and it should work

```
    import mysql.connector
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user='username',passwd='password',host='localhost')
```

Answer (score 1):

If the MySQL80 Command line Client it is closing after you enter the pwd means that you're entering a wrong password. Typically the password that it's asking is the root password.
For such a case check this page:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-installer-workflow.html#mysql-installer-workflow-server and eventually you may have to reset your root pwd and your user accounts.